# how to succeed in installing mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql

I am following Django tutorial, and tried to setup mysqlclient as follows

```
pip install mysqlclient.
```

First time I got an error.

> ```
>    building '_mysql' extension    
>    C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution opt
>    on: 'long_description_content_type'    
>    warnings.warn(msg)  
>    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).
> ```

So I installed Visual Studio 10.0. And this time I got another error.

> ```
>    ...
>     _mysql.c(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h':
> No such file or directory
>     error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
> ```

Can you help me please?

Comment: You should use pip3 for Python3.x right?

Comment: @Mufeed if he's in a venv, `pip install` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

So, it really is not fun setting up Python and\or Django in Windows.  It can be downright nasty.  I would suggest using Anaconda to deal with your Python environments in Windows.  https://www.anaconda.com/ (free)

If you're boxed in by MS Windows, I would also suggest looking into setting up a *nix  virtual machine using https://www.virtualbox.org/ (free).  Not only will it be a great learning experience, but you will find development A LOT easier in *nix based OS's, especially when you're dealing with many projects.  I am sure I will be cursed for saying this, but I think the current go-to for Linux is still Ubuntu https://www.ubuntu.com/ (free).  It's not my flavor, but it's well known for ease of setup, use, and general package management.

**An answer to your problem:**
That said, it appears that you may not have the correct packages installed in your Windows OS.  This usually tells you outright what you're missing, but doesn't tell you what you need to do to make things right.  I had this problem once on my home PC.  For this case, I was able to defeat this problem by updating my development packages in Visual Studio to include C++ Desktop Development.  You should be able to do this with the Visual Studio Community Edition.

You should share the "tutorial" you're following so we can be sure it's right for you.